# UIPagecontrol with animation like apple safari app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipagecontrol

All,

I searched a lot on the web for sample of uipagecontrol. All samples and examples and questions are based on pages which cover the entire screen, and paging using the page control.

I am curious as to the missing part of such samples. Like if you see in the safari app from apple, it shows the webpage in the entire screen till one clicks on a button on bottom right.

then it shrinks the current page, and initiates the whole scroll view and paging and page control.

Is there a easy way to achieve that?

I was kind of trying to create an image of the currentview, shrink the image, and put it in a separate view controller with page control. But then I felt there has to be a easier way. My method seemed a bit cumbersome.

Thanks for any tips or code sample.

Comment: safari on mac? or ipad or iphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [HGPageScrollView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/hgpagescrollview).

[image]